# How does c# string evaluates its own value?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, operator-precedence

Why does this snippet of code

```
string str = 30 + 20 + 10 + "ddd";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

produces `60ddd`,

and this one

```
string str = "ddd" + 30 + 20 + 10;
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

produces `ddd302010`?

Seems like it's very simple, but I can't get my head around it.
Please, show me direction in which I can go in order to find a detailed answer.

Thanks!

Comment: [Operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) and for [C# specifically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually, in this case the ambiguity of `operator +(int, int)` and `operator((string)int, string)` is the cause of confusion.

Comment: However, at the end of the day, relying on Order of Evaluation is a prime example of how to ruin someone's day, and create untold damages from weird bugs.

Comment: @Aron - no, it's the fact that because of the absence of parentheses, in the first expression, the first operation to be performed is clearly `+` between two `int`s and in the second expression, it's `+` between `string` and `int`. Due to associativity.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever WTF. Associativity is an overloaded term?! Why the hell! Associativity means something very different in mathematics, and given the mathematical formalism of functional programming languages, I assumed the mathematically term associativity.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for links!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `+` operators in the expression you show have equal precedence because they're the same operator, hence are evaluated left to right:

```
30 + 20 + 10 + "ddd"
-- + (int, int) returns (int)50
------- + (int, int) returns (int)60
------------ + (object, string) returns (string)"60ddd"
```

Then for the other case:

```
"ddd" + 30 + 20 + 10
----- + (string, object) returns (string)"ddd30"
---------- + (string, object) returns (string)"ddd3020"
--------------- + (string, object) returns (string)"ddd302010"
```

Comment: Not **all** operators are evaluated left to right. Specifically, the first operator in the complete statements under consideration is the assignment operator and that's evaluated last. Similar `2 + 3 * 5` would *not* be evaluated left to right.

Comment: @Damien absolutely correct, thanks for that. See edit, better?

Comment: I'd highlight that this is only because all of these operators are the *same* operator (and hence have equal precedence) and that `+` is left associative in C# (and most other languages as well)

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, that makes perfect sense. Sometimes you just stuck on little things like this, after successfully conquering much more complicated topics)

Answer (score 2):

It's because an expression is evaluated from left side to right side. In the first example 30 + 20 + 10 gives you int + string (30 + 20 + 10) - int, "ddd" - string. In the second example "ddd" + 30 is a string "ddd30" that appends "20" and "10" to it. It's all about the order (unless you have paranthesis).

Answer (score 2):

Operator + has different overloads:

> int + int = int
>
> int + string = string
>
> string + int = string

In Following Expression:

```
string str = 30 + 20 + 10 + "ddd";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

First **30 + 20** got evaluates both are integers so output of operator will be integer which is **50**.

Then **50 + 10** will be evaluated which both are again integers so integer will be output which is **60**.

Then **60 + "ddd"** which is **integer  + string** operation the operator in this case output string so 60 + "ddd" will output **60ddd**.

In Following Expression:

```
string str = "ddd" + 30 + 20 + 10;
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

First **"ddd" + 30** got evaluates in which string + integer operation takes place so output will be **ddd30**.

Then **ddd30 + 20** will get evaluated in which again string + integer operation takes place so output will be **ddd3020**.

Then **ddd3020 + 10** will get evaluated in which again string + integer operation takes place so output will be **ddd302010**.

Answer (score 2):

It's evaluated from left to right. The first example has the numbers first, so it starts by evaluating as numbers. Then it finds out it has to evaluate as string. The second example is the other way around. It starts with string and continues with string.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because, the order of operations if from left to right. But assigment is last operation. 
To assing value first expression must be calculated.